# how to modify a file using Perl, adding and replacing strings between double qoutes

Tags: perl

How can I modify a file (with the following as a part of its contents) using Perl in two following cases. The right position of the string (writing in the proper line with 2 spaces from the first) is important. furthermore,in the following TEST in ${P}/TEST is not constant and change during the running; so we shouldn't use the matching functions with it.
the original file is:

```
! List of Campaigns
! -----------------
CAMPAIGN 1
  "${P}/TEST"
  ## widget = uniline
```

1) adding another string with double quotes, exactly under the "${P}/TEST", e.g. "${P}/XXXXXX" (XXXXXX is defined before in the program). pay attention to the number of campaigns!
so it would become:

```
! List of Campaigns
! -----------------
CAMPAIGN 2
  "${P}/TEST"
  "${P}/XXXXXX"
  ## widget = uniline
```

2) replacing the "${P}/XXXXXX" instead of "${P}/TEST".
so it would become:

```
! List of Campaigns
! -----------------
CAMPAIGN 1
  "${P}/XXXXXX"
  ## widget = uniline
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea. I saw the need for `add_campaign` and `replace_campaign` operations, then took it from there. Your data is in the `__DATA__` pseudofile.

Program output:

```
$ campaigns.pl
! List of Campaigns
! -----------------
CAMPAIGN 3
  "${P}/TEST"
  "${P}/MONKEY"
  "${P}/BLUE"
  ## widget = uniline
```

Program source:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

### main program

# read entire file contents into $data
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

# make an entry in %campaigns for each campaign in $data. Each entry's key 
# is the campaign's name. Its value is irrelevant. We use 1.
my %campaigns;
my $last_campaign_offset;   # index of last campaign found
while ( $data =~ /  "\$\{P\}\/(\w+)"/g ) {
  $campaigns{$1}        = 1;
  $last_campaign_offset = index($data, $');
}

add_campaign('CAMEL');
add_campaign('BLUE');
add_campaign('TEST');   # no-op: campaign already exists
replace_campaign('CAMEL', 'MONKEY');
print $data;


### subroutines

### append a new '  ${P}/FOO' campaign to the data
sub add_campaign {
  my $new_cpn = shift;
  return if exists $campaigns{$new_cpn};

  $new_cpn = qq[\n  "\${P}/$new_cpn"];
  substr($data, $last_campaign_offset) 
    = $new_cpn . substr($data, $last_campaign_offset);
  $last_campaign_offset += length($new_cpn);

  # lastly, increment n in the "CAMPAIGN n" substring
  $data =~ s/(?<=CAMPAIGN )(\d+)/$1 + 1/e;
}

### replace the name of an existing campaign with a new one
sub replace_campaign {
  my ($old_cpn, $new_cpn) = @_;
  $data =~ s/(?<=  "\$\{P\}\/)$old_cpn/$new_cpn/;
}


__DATA__
! List of Campaigns
! -----------------
CAMPAIGN 1
  "${P}/TEST"
  ## widget = uniline
```